# How to add an item after another item in List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to add an item in the list after a specific item.

Example:

```
"Item 1"
"Item 2"
"Item 3"
"Item 4"
```

Add new Item:

```
String newItem = "Item 5"
list.add(newItem);
```

Now I want the item that I added to go below a certain item, Let us assume the latter:

```
"Item 1"
"Item 2"
"Item 5"
"Item 3"
"Item 4"
```

Comment: you can specify index at which you want to insert in ArrayList

Comment: use simply list.add(newItem, 5) and it will be added in the 5th position of the list.

Comment: have a look at [List#add(index,object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) in Java Doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface have the method [void add(int index,
       E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)) method

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).

In your case

```
list.add(2,newItem);
```

<sub>Note : index starts from zero.</sub>

Before using that method. Just check below Exceptions

```
UnsupportedOperationException - if the add operation is not supported by this list
ClassCastException - if the class of the specified element prevents it from being added to this list
NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements
IllegalArgumentException - if some property of the specified element prevents it from being added to this list
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much 
I will manage the exception :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String = "Item 5"
list.add(3,newItem);
```

Will do the trick for you...

its

```
list.add(index,itemtobeadded )
```

Comment: Inserts at 4th position :)

Answer (score 0):

use `LinkedList` class of List interface

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void addItem(String item, String afterItem, List<String> list){
        int location = list.indexOf(afterItem);
        list.add(location+1, item);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestClass obj = new TestClass();
        obj.list.add("1");
        obj.list.add("2");
        obj.list.add("3");
        obj.list.add("4");
        obj.list.add("5");
        for (String s: obj.list)
            System.out.println(s);
        obj.addItem("6", "3", obj.list);
        for (String s: obj.list)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use object array, it is a good habit always

```
Object[] array= new Object[7];
array[0]="Item 1";
array[1]="Item 3";
array[2]="Item 2";
array[3]= array[2]
```

Finally, you can use this, 
If you feel like you want to use as list use this conversion,

```
 List<Object> list= Arrays.asList(array);
```

Thanks and Regards,
Hari